# Loop through range and count based on two variables

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

I'm trying to develop a code that will allow me to loop through a range and create a total count of rows that have 2 criteria.

For the example below I want to loop through rows 2-12 and increase the counter each time a row has the words "Pway" & "T-4". Then place the result in cell G2.
I've played around with loops before but never with two variables.

Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: You can do this with formulas, do you need it to be vba?

Comment: I'm open to all options at the moment.

Comment: `If AnswerToAboveComment = "Yes" Then` you can nest 2 `IF...Then` statements to check for 1 criteria and if met, then check the 2nd, if met increase a counter variable.

Comment: Basically: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Pway",D:D,"T-4")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following formula in G2 and pull it down

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,"Pway",$D$2:D2,"T-4")
```

To get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the VBA solution, too:

```
Sub countTwoCriteria()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, lastR As Long, i As Long, count As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 arr = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).value
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If UCase(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 4)) = UCase("Pway" & "T-4") Then count = count + 1
 Next i
 If count > 0 Then sh.Range("G2").value = count
End Sub
```